# How to LIMIT ArrayDataProvider in yii2?

Tags: arrays, limit, yii2, dataprovider

I am trying create ArrayDataProvider. I am calling dataProvider like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
     'allModels' => $query->from('posts')->all(),
     'pagination' => [
          'pageSize' => 10,
     ],
]);
```

Here I am using pageSize. When I run this code in sql not showing LIMIT, but pagination is working. I have more than 100 posts and all of them loading in all time. Generated SQL Query: `SELECT * FROM`posts.
What I must do to solve this. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `ActiveDataProvider` instead?

Comment: Its simple example. I am using relational tables. There are 6 tables connected to this query.

Comment: I cant use ActiveDataProvider because every item uses another table details. It means for each item need 6 additional queries. If you calculate for 10 item I must run 61 selects.

Comment: OK. As [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html#$allModels-detail) states: `$allModels` is **the data that is not paginated or sorted**. You have to find some way of passing the `pageSize` as a `limit` on the `$query`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'pageSizeLimit' => [5,100],
```